# ngIf block is loading for few seconds and then hiding

Tags: html-table, angular5, angular-ng-if

We have search functionality, with search criteria and table below with search result. I am trying to add "No record found" section for search functionality when there is no records, I have added ngIf condition. But the table has pagination feature as well. we have implemented server side pagination. So wen we have around 1000 records with 10 records per page. It taking time to load data and **its showing "No records found" section for few seconds**  and then loading the data. How will I resolve this? I tried with ngTemplate as well, but I am facing the same issue.

```
<div *ngIf="resultArray!==null && resultArray!==undefined && resultArray.length>0; else displayNoRecordFoundBlock">
    <table>
     </table>
</div>
<ng-template #displayNoRecordFoundBlock>
        <div class="no-result-found"  >
            No records found 
       </div>
</ng-template>
```

This is the code I have used.

Comment: I want to implement angular loader as well.. what is the best option for this

Comment: Link the code of your component that modify `resultArray` plz